# Use JNA to get Local machine Certificate

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, keystore, jna

I'm trying to get a certificate from local machine Windows store. What a want to get is a certificate in the patth "Certificates(Local Computer) --> Personal --> Certificates".

I used this code to access certificate in the path "Certificates - Current User --> Personal --> Certificates

```
 NativeLibrary crypt32 = NativeLibrary.getInstance("Crypt32");
 Function functionCertOpenSystemStore = 
 crypt32.getFunction("CertOpenSystemStoreA");
 Object[] argsCertOpenSystemStore = new Object[] { 0, "MY"};
HANDLE h = (HANDLE) functionCertOpenSystemStore.invoke(HANDLE.class, argsCertOpenSystemStore);
```

Any idea about how to get a certificate from "Certificates(Local Computer) --> Personal --> Certificates"?

I'm trying to use JNA because I read is not posible to access local machine certificates from Java. I only thing I've got is to get "Current user" certificates using keystore like this :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
```

Also I've tried this :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
```

Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [the `wcsa` utility](https://github.com/oddbjornkvalsund/wcsa), which will intercept calls to the Windows Crypto API and let you access the local machine credentials. This is of course a hack around the real problem, [JDK-6782021](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6782021), which was reported ten years ago. But it does let you access the local machine certificates in a pretty painless way!